# Plex Media Server on Ubuntu 12.10 - fighting with HFS+ (I guess)

Tags: 12.10, hfs+, plex

I have Ubuntu 12.10 installed along with Plex Media Server 0.9.7.x (I don't remember, the latest version anyway).
I had Plex set up on a Mac, and I had all of my media content stored in an external HDD formatted as **HFS+ Journaled**. I know Linux can't write on HFS+ (at least easily), but it *reads* natively.

When I try to add a section to my Plex server (from the web manager), it sees my external HDD but it can't see its content.

Is this a known issue? I couldn't find anything about this online.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and all I needed to do was the following:

create a new, for example, a movies directory for plex:

```
$>mkdir Movies
$>chown -R plex:plex Movies
$>mount --bind real_movie_dir Movies
```

start up plex and add the newly generated Movies dir.

**Note:**  Use your freshly created Movies dir and don't use the real one. After a reboot you need to bind the directory before you start the plexmediaserver.

I hope this fixes also your problem.